# Running django-q using elastic beanstalk on aws linux 2 instances

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, scheduled-tasks

I use Elastic Beanstalk on aws to host my webapp which needs a task runner like django q. I need to run it on my instance and am facing difficulty doing that. I found this script https://gist.github.com/codeSamuraii/0e11ce6d585b3290b15a9ad163b9aa06 which does what I need but its for the older version of ec2 instance. So far I know I must run django q post deployment, but is it possible to add the process to the procfile along with starting the wsgi server.

Any help that could point me in the right direction will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Any update on this?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a "Procfile" at the root of your bundle with following content:

```
web: gunicorn --bind 127.0.0.1:8000 --workers=1 --threads=15 mysite.config.wsgi:application
qcluster: python3 manage.py qcluster
```

Obviously, replace "mysite.config.wsgi" with the path to your wsgi.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up not finding a solution, i chose a different tech altogether to fulfill the requirements. It was a crontab making curl requests to a Django server. So on the Django admin I would create task routes linking it to modules in the file storage. And paste the route info in crontab setting and set the appropriate time interval.